# How do I do frequency counts in a SAS DATA step?

Tags: sas

Learning SAS here...

I have a data set, called `salesPeople` that looks like this:

```
personID      personZip
123           47382
123           47382
123           47382
123           47382
123           47382
123           47382
123           47382
123           47382
123           76737
123           76737
123           76737
123           Smallville
123           Smallville
123           Smallville
654           27767
654           27767
654           27767
654           27767
654           27767
654           27767
654           27767
654           83764
654           83764
654           83764
654           83764
654           Metropolis
654           Metropolis
654           Metropolis
654           Metropolis
...           ...
```

For each `personID`, there may be up to several hundred observations. The vast majority of them will be in the same zip code. There may be 1-3 other valid zip codes. And, for each person, there are several observations that will have the city name (for example, Smallville) instead of the city zip (47382, in this case, which is in Smallville). In this data set, the city name, when found in the `personZip` column, ALWAYS corresponds to the most frequent properly entered personZip.

For the purposes of what I'm doing, it is safe to assume that it would be fine to replace all instances of the city name with the most common `personZip`. Here, for example, it would be perfectly acceptable to replace `Smallville` with `47382` and `Metropolis` with `27767`. In fact, that is exactly what I want to do. There are several thousand unique `personID` values in the `salesPeople` data set, and several hundred thousand observations.

What I want to do is to determine the most frequent `personZip` for each `personID` and then to replace the invalid city names with that zip. What is the best way to determine the most frequent `personZip` value and store it so that I can merge it back with the `salesPeople` data set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual way, via `proc summary`. There's probably a shorter way to do this with SQL.

```
proc summary data=salespeople nway;
    class personid personzip;
    output out=tmp (drop=_type_);
run;

proc sort data=tmp;
   by personid descending _freq_;
run;

data tmp;
    set tmp;
    by personid;
    if first.personid;
    /* default zip code is most common code */
    rename personzip = defaultzip;
run;

proc sort data=salespeople;
    by personid;
run;

data salespeople;
    merge salespeople (in=a) tmp (in=b);
    by personid;
    /* replace all non-numeric zips with default value */
    /* assumes non-numerics are rare */
    if personzip * 1 = '' then personzip = defaultzip;
run;
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you yet again! I hadn't seen `PROC SUMMARY` before. By the way, the `(in=a)` and `(in=b)` aren't necessary in the final data step, are they? Or are they implicitly used somehow?

Comment: `proc summary` and `proc means` are your bread-and-butter ways of obtaining summary statistics for groups of observations in SAS. The `in=x` stuff is just boilerplate code I tend to include by default; you don't need it in this example. Check your SAS docs for the `merge` statement for the detailed rundown on what they do.